# Incrementing part of bit mask

Tags: objective-c, c, enums, bit-manipulation, bitmask

Given `enum`:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, BREBreathingProgram) {
    BREBreathingProgramPaceSlowest = 0,
    BREBreathingProgramPaceSlow = 1,
    BREBreathingProgramPaceMedium = 2,
    BREBreathingProgramPaceFast = 3,
    BREBreathingProgramPaceFastest = 4,
    BREBreathingProgramExcludeHold = 1 << 3,
};
```

To increment `BreathingProgramPace` I perform the following calculation:

```
breathingProgram = ((breathingProgram >> 3) & 1) << 3 | (breathingProgram & 3) + 1;
```

Is this the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your 2nd comment to this answer I am rewriting the answer.

You have setup your enum so the first 3 bits represent a single value for the pace. You can have a value up to 7.

The fourth bit represents your "hold".

You wish to have some pace value and also some other bits set. You then wish to be able to increment that pace while keeping the other bits as they are.

This is simple.

```
breathingProgram++;
```

A simple increment is all you need. Example. Lets say your pace is set to "Slow" and the "hold" bit is set. This gives a value of 9 (1 for "slow" and 8 for "hold").

Now you wish to increment the pace to "medium". Simply incrementing from 9 to 10 does this.

While this works there is the risk that you could over increment the value and start messing with the flags.

A safer (and more complicated) way would be:

```
breathingProgram = (breathingProgram & 0xF8) | (((breathingProgram & 0x07) + 1) & 0x07);
```

This ensures that you can't do the increment past the allotted "pace" values and into the flags area. This would actually wrap the "pace" value back to zero if you went too far.

Comment: I was planning to use the first 3 bits for the `Pace` value and the rest as a bit mask, `BREBreathingProgramExcludeHold` being the first bit. Isn't that a (partial) bit mask?

Comment: To put it simply — wouldn't incrementing the entire `NSUInteger` change `BREBreathingProgramExcludeHold` and other bits that I'm planning to add?

Comment: That's what doesn't make sense. What bits do you mean? As it stands now, your enum is not really setup for a bit mask. Why don't you provide more details in your question about how this will be used and provide some examples.

Comment: Basically, I want to do something like `UIViewAnimationOptions` where some bits are part of a value (like Transition or Curve) and some are used as flags (like AllowUserInteraction). In my case, I'd like to have Pace (that will incremented and decremented) and a bunch of flags like ExcludeHold.

Comment: See my rewritten answer based on your last comment.

Comment: Light bulb moment! Everything's clear now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW - using the mask `0xF8` is only good if you are using 8 bits total. If you need 16 or 32 or whatever, adjust that mask accordingly - `0xFFF8` for 16 bits, etc.